Git pre-commit : Get user y/n option to proceed
Is there a way to get the user y/n option when doing a git hook? For instance after running a pre-commit  ruff linter check, the user may decide not add the changes recommended.
If so, is there a way to continue with the changes through the shell pre-commit file (in .git/hooks) itself by adding a would you like to continue with the commit? option?
I'm aware there's aNo verify commit option in vscode, but that's not what I'm looking for.

what have you tried? what isn't working?

You shouldn't change the contents of the commit in a pre-commit hook, so in general there isn't a recommended way to do this.

Pre-commit is just a pre-execution script and cannot interact with custom parameters.
If you want to control the standardization of commit message content, you can refer to the plugins provided by intellij idea, such as "commit message template" plugin.

This is an English-language site. The comments in Chinese were basically redundant anyway, so I removed them.

In VSCode I can't get the message appear at all, it would just show a message saying "1 file left unchanged" , if there are changes found with the git hook
